# Star based rating not accurate with decimal values

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a star based rating with decimal values that works but doesn't look very accurate unless the rating is a whole number. For example when the rating is 3.7 it looks like:

[image: this]

When it's for example 3.4 looks like:

[image: this].

Is there anyway it could look a bit more accurate?

I change the rank value with jQuery by taking a value from a table and changing the width by multiplying it by 20 in order to get percentage value in the following way:

```js
var starRating1 = table[0][4] * 20;
$('#star-ratings-top1').width(starRating1 + '%');
```

```css
.star-ratings {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  color: pink;
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.star-ratings .star-ratings-top {
  color: gold;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.star-ratings .star-ratings-bottom {
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="star-ratings">
  <div class="star-ratings-top" id="star-ratings-top1">
    <span>★</span>
    <span>★</span>
    <span>★</span>
    <span>★</span>
    <span>★</span>
  </div>
  <div class="star-ratings-bottom">
    <span>☆</span>
    <span>☆</span>
    <span>☆</span>
    <span>☆</span>
    <span>☆</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by 'more accurate'? A star rating with 1DP precision is already higher than most I've seen.

Comment: the image seems very accurate for me

Comment: I think what they mean is that this doesn’t “look” like proper .7 or .4 to the human eye. The basic problem here is that we have a linear distribution of the rating on the horizontal axis - but the star shape is not equally “distributed” over the width as well. .3 gives us just two little “spikes” that are filled with color, but it doesn’t look like that was actually .3 of the actual area the star shapes covers (because it isn’t.)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a designer, not coding help.

How about the following:
1) Make the stars in class *star-ratings-bottom* solid black
2) Place on a gray background

Answer (score 0):

You can also try in other way..find an image with all ratings(3.4,3.7)..and give it position top left accordingly

```css
.small-star-rating {
 background-image: url(https://hostingpill.com/cheap-web-hosting/newimages/small-stars.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 0.7rem;
 width: 6.1428571429rem;
        position: relative;
        top: 1.0714285714rem;
        left: 1.4285714286rem;
}
.small-star-rating.stars-4 {
 background-position: 0 -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="small-star-rating stars-4"></div>
```